# How can I make my image to be blur like the one in my message content?

Tags: unity, c#

[image: blur]

Should I use post processing v2 depth of field or something else ? I want to do it for my main menu.
I have my own image and I want to make it blur like this one.

I changed my images texture type to Sprite (2D and UI) and assigned it to a ui image component.
Now the question how to make it blur ?

Comment: Presumably you started by searching for "unity blur effect" in your favourite search engine. What have you tried based on the guides you found so far?

Comment: @DMGregory The results is to use a shader.

Comment: Great. How have you tried using a shader for this so far?